# ensuring security of .DLL / .so

Tags: c++, windows, security, shared-libraries

I have a shared library mylib.so that is loaded in at run time. I need to ensure that it loads in the right mylib.so / mylib.dll. Is there a cross platform (Win/Mac/Linux) method of ensuring that the right shared library is loaded in.

I'm thinking of doing a checksum on the .dll, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the actual .dll that's loaded in at run-time. (this is all in C++)

Comment: If you do not have trusted hardware your software solution is going to be a show of security.  If this is a banking or more secure type app, NSA standards may be appropriate.  If you are attempting something like copy protection, it will only working nobody cares.

Comment: I guess on windows you could use [`LoadLibraryEx(...,LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179\(v=vs.85\).aspx) and do some kind of validation before loading the DLL, but I doubt it'll actually be beneficiary (though you might be able to catch accidental loading of a wrong version).

Comment: Another option is to use static libraries.  Then all code is in your EXE file and the issue disappears.

Comment: Yes static libraries are another way to go. Though our current library  only compiles to .dlls

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use static libraries due to a certain insanity with static variables

Comment: Static variables are scoped to a file and should not be a problem.  Non-static global variables would be a problem.  But they are evil anyway and it is good to remove them.

Comment: Why do you want to check the DLL version?  Is it a security thing?

Comment: Yes its a security thing - I need to make sure the right dlls are loaded in at load-time (not run time)

Comment: But load time is run time.  When a DLL is loaded by a process, the DLL can run arbitrary code.  If the DLL is from a hacker, during load the bad DLL could read the entire process and send it to a black hat web site.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows only solution, look at

```
HMODULE h = GetModuleHandle( "mylib" );
char name[ 300 ];
DWORD rc = GetModuleFileName( h, name, sizeof(name) );
```

I am not saying this helps or hinders actual security.

Comment: This will only work once "mylib" has been loaded into the process, at which point any hope of security is too late (if there ever were any).